# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined | discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So, I was following the official discord.js docs tutorial, and it doesn't work. I'm new to js and discord.js so I might just be missing out a little bit. I did modify it a bit so it fits my project so it may also be that. It says this.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at Object.execute (C:\bot1\commands\help.js:12:23)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\bot1\index.js:40:32)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\bot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\bot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\bot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\bot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\bot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\bot1\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

Here's the code

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: 'List all of my commands or info about a specific command.',
    execute(message, args) {
        const data = [];
        const { commands } = message.client;

        var prefix = "e!";

        if (!args.length) {
            data.push('Here\'s a list of all my commands:');
            data.push(commands.map(command => command.name).join(', '));
            data.push(`\nYou can send \`${prefix}help [command name]\` to get info on a specific command`);

            return message.author.send(data, { split: true })
                .then(() => {
                    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
                    message.reply('I\'ve sent you a DM with all my commands');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(`Could not send help DM to ${message.author.tag}.\n`, error);
                    message.reply('It seems like I can\'t DM you');
                });
        }

        const name = args[0].toLowerCase();
        const command = commands.get(name) || commands.find(c => c.aliases && c.aliases.includes(name));

        if (!command) {
            return message.channel.send('That\'s not a valid command.');
        }

        data.push(`**Name:** ${command.name}`);

        if (command.aliases) data.push(`**Aliases:** ${command.aliases.join(', ')}`);
        if (command.description) data.push(`**Description:** ${command.description}`);
        if (command.usage) data.push(`**Usage:** ${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}`);

        message.channel.send(data, { split: true });
    },
};
```

Comment: ` data.push(commands.map(command => command.name).join(', '));` Something is causing `commands` to be undefined. Check what properties are available  on `message.client` where you are trying to extract commands from.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're actually assigning `client.commands = new Discord.Collection();`

Since you're already passing message and args you might as well pass the client from where you handle messages

`execute(client, message, args)`